# Code for Basic Site Search

Tags: php, html, mysql, sql

I'm having problems with the basic search on my site, because it only finds matches if the word order is an exact match.

For example, if I search Shoes Red it won't show results for Red Shoes.

If you search for Red Shoe Laces it won't show results for Red Laces (as the word shoe throws off this order).  Below is the code that I believe the search box is using.  Can anyone tell me how to "loosen" up this search so it's either more broad or so exact word order isn't necessary?

This is the current code:  My php code knowledge is basic, so if possible reference the exact spots on how to fix this (if possible):

```
case 'search':
          if (intval($filter) != 0) {       
              $filter = JString::strtolower($filter);
              $id = intval($filter);
              $search .= $temp."(a.id = $id OR LOWER(a.ad_headline) LIKE '%".$this->_db->getEscaped($filter,true)."%' OR LOWER(a.ad_text) LIKE '%".$this->_db->getEscaped($filter,true)."%')";
          } else {
              $filter = JString::strtolower($filter);
              $search .= $temp."(LOWER(a.ad_headline) LIKE '%".$this->_db->getEscaped($filter,true)."%' OR LOWER(a.ad_text) LIKE '%".$this->_db->getEscaped($filter,true)."%')";
          }
          break;
          }
          }
      }
      return $search;
 }
```

Any ideas here?

Comment: Can you post the query formed from above code?

Comment: You should read up a bit on MySQLs fulltext capabilities.

Comment: For the benefit of this page, I commented on your duplicate question to suggest Apache Solr or Lucene. Read more here: stackoverflow.com/q/2010663/472495

Answer (score 1):

You need to use `Full-Text Search` Function

See below syntax:

**`MATCH`**`(field_name1,field_name2)`**`AGAINST`**`(value)`

In your context, something like below:

```
$search .= $temp."MATCH(a.ad_headline,a.ad_text) AGAINST ('".$this->_db->getEscaped($filter,true)."')";
```

For more details, [Refer link](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en//fulltext-search.html)

Comment: Hi, I tried your fix:  $search .= $temp."MATCH(a.ad_headline,a.ad_text) AGAINST ('".$this->_db->getEscaped($filter,true)."')";    However it didn't pull any results after this change..  Perhaps there is an error somewhere?

Comment: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/fulltext-natural-language.html - read this. Might be usefull

Comment: Full text search would be the way to go. If you have some spare time can I suggest Udacity's _Introduction to Computing Science_ course https://www.udacity.com/course/cs101 in which you learn how to build web crawlers, hash maps for search indexes etc. Note - this is in Python and did not use a database when I took it, but the underlying concepts are the same.

Answer (score 0):

Full text search is not always available with every database.

This is the poor man's alternative.

I generally split the query on whitespaces and then have lots of like conditions, however there is no weighting of results, but it narrow down the results somewhat.

```
 $pattern_parts = preg_split('/\s+/', $pattern);

 $sql = "SELECT * FROM tablename WHERE " 

 foreach ($pattern_parts as $pattern_part) {
    $sql.= " (field1 LIKE '%$pattern_part%' OR field2 LIKE '%$pattern_part%') AND ';
 }

 $sql .= " (fieldx = 'y') "; // other conditions go here
 $sql .= "ORDER BY field1 ASC";
```

Obviously you will need to take care of escaping data, etc

If you need beyond what Fulltext search can offer, also check out phplucence